# Should I delete temporary files created by my script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, operating-system, temp

It's a common question not specifically about some language or platform. Who is responsible for a file created in systems $TEMP folder?
If it's my duty, why should I care where to put this file? I can place it anywhere with same result.
If it's OS responsibility, can I forgot about this file right after use?

Thanks and sorry for my basic English.

Comment: Yes, you should. Most operating systems regularly clean their temp directories (on boot and/or using a cron job), but that may not happen that frequently. There's few things more annoying to a sysadmin that processes that leak vast amounts of temporary files.

Comment: You can use Python's [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) in a `with` statement to create temporary files that are automatically cleaned up for you as soon as you exit the `with` block: `with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp: ...`. This even works if your code terminates because of an unhandled exception, so there's no need to do the `try...finally` dance yourself.

Comment: @LukasGraf, well, then why do I need this $TEMP folder mechanism?

Comment: @LukasGraf, I know about python's tempfile context manager. It's same as my duty, anyway.

Comment: Several different reasons. For one, it's a predefined location where you're guaranteed to have write access. Next, some operating systems have their temporary directory on a separate partition for reasons of better resource management (to avoid filling up the root partition for example), a specially optimized file system or even in memory for better performance.

Comment: @LukasGraf comprehensibly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you should remove the temporary files that you create.

Recall that the $TEMP directory is a shared resource that other programs can use.  Failure to remove the temporary files will have an impact on the other programs that use $TEMP.

What kind of impacts?  That will depend upon the other programs.  If those other programs create a lot of temporary files, then their execution will be slower as it will take longer to create a new temporary file as the directory will have to be scanned on each temporary file creation to ensure that the file name is unique.

Consider the following (based on real events) ...
In years past, my group at work had to use the Intel C Compiler.  We found that over time, it appeared to be slowing down.  That is, the time it took to run our sanity tests using it took longer and longer.  This also applied to building/compiling a single C file.  We tracked the problem down.
ICC was opening, stat'ing and reading every file under $TEMP.  For what purpose, I know not.  Although the argument can be made that the problem lay with the ICC, the existence of the files under $TEMP was slowing it and our development team down.  Deleting those temporary files resulted in the sanity checks running in less than a half hour instead of over two--a significant time saver.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard and no common rules. In most OSs, the files in the temporary folder will pile up. Some systems try to prevent this by deleting files in there automatically after some time but that sometimes causes grief, for example with long running processes or crash backups.

The reason for `$TEMP` to exist is that many programs (especially in early times when RAM was scarce) needed a place to store temporary data since "super computers" in the 1970s had only a few KB of RAM (yes, N*1024 bytes where N is << 100 - you couldn't even fit the image of your mouse cursor into that). Around 1980, 64KB was a lot.

The solution was a folder where anyone could write. Security wasn't an issue at the time, memory was.

Over time, OSs started to get better systems to create temporary files and to clean them up but backwards compatibility prevented a clean, "work for all" solution.

So even though you know where the data ends up, you are responsible to clean up the files after yourself. To make error analysis easier, I tend to write my code in such a way that files are only deleted when everything is fine - that way, I can look at intermediate results to figure out what is wrong. But logging is often a better and safer solution.

Related: [Memory prices 1957-2014](http://www.jcmit.com/memoryprice.htm) 12KB of Ram did cost US $4'680,- in 1973.